# strtok only returning one token

Tags: c, delimiter, strtok

I'm writing a simple shell that accepts some standard commands like cd and ls in C. I'm trying to implement a feature where the user can enter a ";" in between commands so that a bunch of commands can be written on the same line and be executed separately. So if I input "cd Desktop; ls" the shell should cd to Desktop and print the what's in the directory. The problem is it only executes the first command. Here's my main method:

```
char input[1024];

while(1)
{
    printf("%s ", prompt);
    fgets(input, 1024, stdin);

    char delims[] = ";";
    char *result = NULL;
    result = strtok( input, delims );

    while( result != NULL )
    {
        printf("%s\n", result);

        char * copy = malloc(strlen(result) + 1); //Create a copy of the input token
        strcpy(copy, result);

        format(copy);

        if(programs)
        {
            handle();
            cleanup(programs);
            programs = NULL;
        }
        free(copy);
        result = strtok( NULL, delims );
        cmdno++;
    }
}
```

First I try to break up the input into tokens based on ";" and then feed the token to the format() method which looks like this:

```
int format(char input[])
{
    input = strtok(input, "\n");
    ...
}
```

I know that strtok makes changes to the original string, which is why I create a copy of the token first before passing it to format. Is what I'm doing correct??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mix multiple `strtok` calls. Here's what's happening:

- You start splitting `input` so **`strtok` takes note and stores stuff internally**
- You take a break from splitting `input`

  - You start splitting `copy` so again `strtok` takes note, **thereby destroying the previous info**
- At this point `strtok` only knows about the `copy` business and doesn't know anything about the original `input`.

The main problem is that **`strtok` doesn't know that you're doing two things at the same time**. From its point of view, you simply started processing a different string before finishing the first string.

---

Possible solutions:

- Use [`strtok_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) if you have it. It's not standard C (but it is standard POSIX). The `r` stands for reentrant
- Use your own splitting function (strchr / looping etc)
- **Change your program logic such that you don't need to split `copy` before finishing with `input`**

About that last point:

- Keep an array of `char *` and fill it with `strtok` without pausing to split sub-tokens. So each element should be a different command
- When you're done with the `";"` split, start processing each of the array elements

Comment: Can you propose an alternate solution then?

Comment: I see what you mean. If I were to use strtok_r do I just add the _r to all instances of strtok? Or just in the format method?

Comment: @vince88 **Short answer: each time**. You need to study the manual page for `strtok_r` and understand the `lasts` parameter. See the link in the answer.

Comment: I wound up changing my program logic like you suggested and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
char line[1024];
char *token;
while (1) {
  printf("$ ");
  fgets(line, 1000, stdin);
  token = strtok(line, ";");
  while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ";");
  }
}
```